# Use the second squeeze theorem and prove $\lim _{n\to \infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Use the second squeeze theorem  and prove  $\lim _{n\to \infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=0$

What is squeeze second theorem

what i know about squeeze theorem is

If the limits of the sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\},$ and $\{b_n\},$ are convergent with $a_n ≤ b_n ≤ c_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = L$
 then $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n =L$

Comment: You can describe this with the squeeze theorem you mention as is., just look at the two sequences $\frac{-1}{n^2}$ and $\frac{+1}{n^2}$ and how these relate to yours.

Comment: @ JMoravitz ....sir what is second squeeze theorem

Comment: What one person calls one thing another person might call something else.  I do not know of something called "the second squeeze theorem" but it doesn't matter since the only squeeze theorem I do know about, the one you mentioned already, already works for a proof.

Comment: @ JMoravitz ...thank you sir for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use that $$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|\le \frac{1}{n^2}$$ and this tends to zero for $n$ tends to infinity

Answer (score 2):

$$ -\frac{1}{n^2}\le \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\le  \frac{1}{n^2}$$